# Timeout exception while reading data from HttpURLConnection in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-pubsub

I am running an application on Google App Engine which calls a Http URL of my 
web application(running on Glassfish) to read data using inputstream. Here is 
my code snippet.

```
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
URL url = new URL(Http URL);
conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(0); 
conn.setReadTimeout(0);  
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
System.out.println("response code=" + conn.getResponseCode());
byte b[] = new byte[2048];
InputStream is = url.openStream();
int len;
while ((len=is.read(b))!=-1){
    os.write(b, 0, len);
    System.out.println("len=" + len);
}
```

But I am getting "Timeout while fetching URL:" exception.

I have tried URLFetchService too, but exception remains same

```
URLFetchService urlFetchService = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
URL url = new URL(Http URL);
Future future = urlFetchService.fetchAsync(url);
HTTPResponse response1 = (HTTPResponse)future.get();
byte[] content = response1.getContent();
int responseCode = response1.getResponseCode();
List<HTTPHeader> headers = response1.getHeaders();
System.out.println("responseCode=" + responseCode);
```

Please advise how to proceed. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why are you setting the timeouts to zero?  That just tests for a connection.  Try setting them to, say, 6000.

Comment: I read somewhere that setting timeout would wait for infinity, so gave it a try. I already tried to set it to 6000, but it seems that any value in these 2 methods doesn't change the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this exception. Http URL of my web application(running on Glassfish) was an internal IP address.  On attempting to read data from Google, it should be a publicly accessible IP address.